# Show a message if the file is opened or closed after a button klick

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have a UserControl and ViewModel and it needs to show a message (TextBlock) after I klick the CheckConfigurationCommand Button. The content of the message depends on the nameFile.config File if it is opened or not. If the file is opened, after clicking the button, the message should show: "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is open.".
If the file is NOT open, the message should show: "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is NOT open.".

With my code, it shows only one message, that the file is open altough the file is not open, can you show me where is the mistake?

Here is my XAML and my ViewModel:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PTC_Konfiguration.View.ConfigurationReviewUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PTC_Konfiguration.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Opened File:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OpenedFilePath}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
            <Button Content="Check Configuration" Command="{Binding CheckConfigurationCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
private string openedFilePath;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string OpenedFilePath
        {
            get { return openedFilePath; }
            set
            {
                if (openedFilePath != value)
                {
                    openedFilePath = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand CheckConfigurationCommand { get; }

        public ConfigurationReviewViewModel()
        {
            CheckConfigurationCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckConfiguration);
        }

        private void CheckConfiguration()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Path";

            if (FileIsOpen(filePath))
            {
                OpenedFilePath = "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is open.";
            }
            else if (FileIsNotOpen(filePath))
            {
                OpenedFilePath = "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is not open.";
            }
        }

        private bool FileIsOpen(string filePath)
        {
            return File.Exists(filePath);
        }

        private bool FileIsNotOpen(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    fs.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried single step debugging through your methods?

Comment: Yes and it skips the FileIsNotOpen

Comment: `File.Exists` does *not* tell you if you successfully opened a file. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File.Exists()` method written in the `FileIsOpen()` method is a method to check whether a file exists.

If I understand correctly, `FileIsOpen()` wants to determine whether there is a deadlock because the file is open.

There is no reason to have two methods. I think you just need to reverse the return value in the `FileIsNotOpen()` method.

I think one `IF` is enough.

```cs
  private void CheckConfiguration()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Path";

            if (FileIsOpen(filePath))
            {
                OpenedFilePath = "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is open.";
            }
            else
            {
                OpenedFilePath = "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is not open.";
            }
        }

        private bool FileIsOpen(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I hope this is the functionality you want.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it stills shows only the first content "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is open." altough the file is closed..

Comment: @drntvc 
I was confused for a moment too. The return value of `FileIsOpen()` was changed and modified. Would you like to check it out?

Comment: Now when the file IS OPEN, the TextBlock content shows this message: "Opened File: The nameFile.config with DC is not open." :D

This is the exact same thing that is happening to me for 2 days now :D

Comment: To check whether the file is actually causing a deadlock, open the file according to the questioner's scenario and try moving or renaming the file.

If it succeeds, you would expect that the file is not deadlocked.

Comment: I changed the name from the file and closed it and the message changed, than I opened the file again and clicked on the button and the message stayed the same, it gave the wrong message from its status. Same thing happened when moving the file.

Comment: I think the sequence of steps you've just taken doesn't lead to a deadlock.

Comment: Somehow this codeblock is making problems? catch (IOException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

When I change the return values, it also changes the content of the Textblock, but it does not read the status of the file?

Comment: It appears that the problem is not with the code, but with your 'Open' operation. Actually, the 'Open' operation doesn't cause a deadlock on the file, which allows for modifications to the file's contents, name, and so on. This means that these changes cannot be detected by the code.

Comment: I'll try to fix it, but thanks for the help and answers! I will give you vote UP. :)